# AWS Textract - GetDocumentAnalysisRequest only returns correct results for first page of document

Tags: amazon-textract

I have written code to extract tables and name value pairs from pdf using Amazon Textract. I followed this example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/async-analyzing-with-sqs.html
which was in sdk for java version 1.1.
I have refactored it for version 2.

This is an async process that only applies to multi page documents. When i get back the results it is pretty accurate for first page. But the consecutive pages are mostly empty rows. The documents i parse are scanned so the quality is not great. However if i take a jpg of individual pages and use the one page operation, i.e. AnalyzeDocumentRequest, each page comes out good. Also Amazon Textract tryit service renders the pages correctly.

So the error must be in my code but can't see where.
As you see it all happens in here :

```java
    GetDocumentAnalysisRequest documentAnalysisRequest = GetDocumentAnalysisRequest.builder().jobId(jobId)
                    .maxResults(maxResults).nextToken(paginationToken).build();

            response = textractClient.getDocumentAnalysis(documentAnalysisRequest);
```

and i can't really do any intervention.

The most likely place I could make a mistake would be in the util file that gathers the page and table blocks i.e. here:

```java
  PageModel pageModel = tableUtil.getTableResults(blocks);
```

But that works perfectly for the first page, and i could also see in the response object above, that the number of blocks returned are much less.

Here is the full code:

```java
private DocumentModel getDocumentAnalysisResults(String jobId) throws Exception {

        int maxResults = 1000;
        String paginationToken = null;
        GetDocumentAnalysisResponse response = null;
        Boolean finished = false;

        int pageCount = 0;
        DocumentModel documentModel = new DocumentModel();
        // loops until pagination token is null
        while (finished == false) {
            GetDocumentAnalysisRequest documentAnalysisRequest = GetDocumentAnalysisRequest.builder().jobId(jobId)
                    .maxResults(maxResults).nextToken(paginationToken).build();

            response = textractClient.getDocumentAnalysis(documentAnalysisRequest);

            // Show blocks, confidence and detection times
            List<Block> blocks = response.blocks();
            PageModel pageModel = tableUtil.getTableResults(blocks);
            pageModel.setPageNumber(pageCount++);
            Map<String,String> keyValues = formUtil.getFormResults(blocks);
            pageModel.setKeyValues(keyValues);
            documentModel.getPages().add(pageModel);
            paginationToken = response.nextToken();
            if (paginationToken == null)
                finished = true;
        }
        return documentModel;

    }
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find the solution. I instead made jpg image of each page of pdf and used the AnalyzeDocumentRequest to get the result for each page separately and then combined them to get result for the entire document.

Comment: Found the solution. Please use nexttoken parameter which will give you next batch of response.

Answer (score 0):

if the response has NextToken, then you need to recall textract and pass in the NextToken to get the next batch of Blocks.
I am not sure how to do this in Java but here is the python example from AWS repo
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-serverless-large-scale-document-processing/blob/master/src/jobresultsproc.py

For my solution, I did a simple if response['NextToken'] then recall method and concat the response['Blocks'] to my current list.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if you have NextToken and get the result from that page also If you need you can merge the results

```
var results = textractAnalysisService.GetJobResults(jobId);
```

```
if (results.NextToken != null)
{
 var secondResult = textractAnalysisService.GetJobResults(jobId, results.NextToken);

}
```

```
  public GetDocumentAnalysisResponse GetJobResults(string jobId, string nextToken = null)
        {

            var response = this.textract.GetDocumentAnalysisAsync(new GetDocumentAnalysisRequest
            {
                JobId = jobId,
                NextToken = nextToken
            });
            response.Wait();
            return response.Result;
        }
```