# Amazon Textract returns different results returns different results between WebApp Demo, AnalyzeDocumentRequest and StartDocumentAnalysisRequest

Tags: amazon-textract

this is my first question on StackOverFlow, I would like to extract key-value pairs (FORMS) from a (scanned) PDf document via Amazon Textract. What I have noticed, however, is that **some key-value pairs returned by the webapp demo** (https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/textract/home?region=us-east-2#/demo) **are absent from the methods that can be implemented in the code**.

Furthermore, **between these two methods**, **the Synchronous method** (AnalyzeDocumentRequest), which does not accept PDF but forces a pre-conversion of the document into an image, in turn **finds key-value pairs** ([Sync Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf9xR.png)) **which the Asynchronous method does not**. ([Async Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAvIY.jpg))

The problem is similar to this guy's, when he talks about the difference in results between the two methods of analyzing the document : [AWS Textract - GetDocumentAnalysisRequest only returns correct results for first page of document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66159937/aws-textract-getdocumentanalysisrequest-only-returns-correct-results-for-first)

The code implementation is equal to these example:

- Synchronous Method: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/examples-extract-kvp.html
- Asynchronous Method: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-textract-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/async-analyzing-with-sqs.md

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if you do the rasterization of the pdf yourself, you might end up with a different image quality than the one that is done by the Textract servers, which could in turn give you different results.

Comment: I have the same issue and we're taking the NextToken as Jonathan Smith is suggesting. There are several key-values present in the form analysis of the document, and these key-valuess are not present in the result of the api call.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem recently. The demo website provided by AWS found 50 fields, our own code using the provided API yielded 30 fields.

After some trial land error and a lot of googling we found that the response returned by `GetDocumentAnalysisAsync` included a `NextToken` which is used to ask for more results. Turns out we had to call `GetDocumentAnalysisAsync` again with this token (rinse-and-repeat) until the result response no longer included a `NextToken`.

At that point we knew we had all the data.